# Handling Variable Size Sub-Batches inside a mini batch in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently trying to implement a modified form (discussed later) of [this paper](http://aclweb.org/anthology/P16-1200).

In particular equations 5,7 and 8 can be summarized as follows:

Given an input batch of data points **x**, we calculate the following value

**e<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub>Ar** (where A and r are tensors of appropriate dimensions)

Then normalize the values of **e<sub>i</sub>** across a batch

[image]

and finally calculate a single representation for the entire batch

[image]

This works fine. A point worth mentioning is that these batches are not randomly created but rather represent a specific group of data points collectively forming a group representation. Thus in a particular batch we can only pass data points that represent a particular group. In this case, the batch sizes are variable since each group can have different number of data points. Now for my use case, we go one step further.

Let us assume we have a pseudo batch size of 32.

In a single training step, we pass K<sub>1</sub> + K<sub>2</sub> .... K<sub>32</sub> = K data points where K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub> .... K<sub>32</sub> represent the different sizes of the subgroups. And so after the evaluation of the above equations, instead of getting 1 output representation for the entire batch, we would want 32 output representations, 1 for each group. What would be the best way to do such kind of an operation?

One thing that could be (or probably would be) necessary is to pass group numbers to an additional placeholder, something as follows

Data_Point 1      -->       Sub-Batch 1

Data_Point 2      -->       Sub-Batch 1

Data_Point 3      -->       Sub-Batch 1

Data_Point 4      -->       Sub-Batch 2

Data_Point 5      -->       Sub-Batch 2

....

....

Data_Point K      -->       Sub-Batch 32

However, I am unable to come up with a definitive technique to go further. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT 1: I have created a small toy setup of the above problem [here](https://gist.github.com/DushyantaDhyani/13d83f939038ca86d0a18868febfeeed)

As you can see, currently the shape of generated group representation is 1*10. However it should be 5*10

EDIT 2: I got it to work but I am concerned about the correctness/optimization of my code. Would be great if someone could help me in checking if the code is correct and if yes, could there be any way in which I could further optimize my code.

For now, I use a while loop to loop over every sub-group and use a mask operation to extract the subset of values. The resulting group representation is assigned to a particular index in a TensorArray Object. Since each subgroup is independent of the other, I can (probably) parallelize all the iterations of the while loop.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

seed = 12
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)

max_sequence_length = 10
pseudo_batch_size = 5

def get_data():
    data_list, group_num_list = [], []
    sub_group_sizes = list(np.random.randint(2, 6, pseudo_batch_size))
    for group_num, size in enumerate(sub_group_sizes):
        group_data = np.random.random_sample((size, max_sequence_length))
        data_list.extend(group_data)
        group_num_list.extend([group_num] * size)

    print("Number of Data Points %s" % (len(data_list)))
    print("Group Sizes %s" % (sub_group_sizes))
    data_x = np.array(data_list)
    print("Shape of Data %s" % (data_x.shape,))

    return (data_x, group_num_list)


def get_attention_weighted_rep(x):
    x_prime = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(x, W_att), W_r)
    attention = tf.nn.softmax(x_prime)
    group_representation = tf.reduce_sum(attention * x, axis=0, keep_dims=True)
    return group_representation


def loop_body(initial_loop_val, outputs_x):
    eq_op = tf.equal(input_group_num, initial_loop_val)
    mask_op_x = tf.boolean_mask(input_x, eq_op)
    group_representation = get_attention_weighted_rep(mask_op_x)
    outputs_x = outputs_x.write(initial_loop_val, group_representation)
    return initial_loop_val + 1, outputs_x


def condition(initial_loop_val, outputs_x):
    return tf.less(initial_loop_val, pseudo_batch_size)


train_x, group_num_list = get_data()

initial_loop_val = tf.constant(0)
input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, max_sequence_length], name="input_x")
input_group_num = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="input_group_num")

W_r = tf.get_variable("w_r", [max_sequence_length, 1],
                      initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())

W_att = tf.diag(tf.truncated_normal([max_sequence_length], stddev=0.001))

outputs_x = tf.TensorArray(size=pseudo_batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

# Since each sub group is independent of the others, we can execute all sub-groups in parallel
initial_loop_val, outputs_x = tf.while_loop(cond=condition, body=loop_body, loop_vars=(initial_loop_val, outputs_x),
                                            parallel_iterations=pseudo_batch_size)
group_representations = outputs_x.concat()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    generated_group_representation = sess.run(group_representations, feed_dict={input_x: train_x,
                                                                                input_group_num: group_num_list})
    print("Shape of Generated Group Representation is %s" % (generated_group_representation.shape,))
    # print("Generated Group Representation is %s" % generated_group_representation)
```

EDIT 3:

The Usage of Boolean_mask leads to the following warning

> "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

For my particular use case, if this is actually a memory concern as the warning message says, are there any alternatives to the mask operation that I can use? I am not sure how the [tf.dynamic_partition](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition) operation which has been suggested in some SO posts can be used (efficiently) here

Answer (score 1):

If your code is assuming that you'll fill in `w_att` and `w_r` later with the correct values, then it should do what you think: produce a TensorArray in which each element is calculated across a psuedo-batch. You'll have to think pretty hard and carefully to make sure these are filled the right way. It is quite inefficient since you are doing multiple (potentially very large/sparse) matrix multiplies.

---

If you know ahead of time exactly how many pseudo-batches you will have, then you should use `tf.dynamic_partition` with your `group_num_list`

```
x_partitions = tf.dynamic_partition(x, group_num_list, pseudo_batch_size)
```

`x_partitions` is then a python list of Tensors where `x_partitions[0]` is a stack of the vectors from `x` for which the index of `group_num_list` was `0`.  e.g. (not actually code)

```
given    x.shape == [5, 100] and 
  group_num_list == [0,0,0,1,1],
then   len(x_partitions) == 2 and 
   x_partitions[0].shape == [3, 100]
   x_partitions[1].shape == [2, 100]
```

You can then do whatever else you were going to do on just one partition on all of the partitions with a native python loop (although this creates a bunch of extra nodes in your graph, there's very little computation overhead).

I'm going to modify your `get_attention_weighted_rep`, mostly assuming different names and feeding in all of the components. I'm going to call it `x_to_s`

```
def x_to_s(x, A, r):
    e = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(x, A), r)
    alpha = tf.softmax(e)
    return tf.reduce_sum(x * e, 0, keep_dims=True)
```

Once this has been done per partition, you can concatenate them back together to get an `s` across all pseudo-batches:

```
# following on from our example earlier, let's use x_to_s 
# which takes an x with x.shape = [None, 100]
# and returns a tensor with shape = [1, 100]
s_parts = []
for p in x_partitions:
    # calculate/find A and r for this x
    s_parts.append(x_to_s(p, A, r))
s = tf.concat(s_parts)
# this makes s.shape = [2, 100]
```

If you want a dynamic number of pseudo batches at run time; then I don't think there's a simple way.

I didn't read enough of the paper to know how A and r are calculated, sorry.

Comment: Well that definitely gave me a few pointers. I had initially come across the dynamic_partition function but could not connect it to my problem. My technique works for now as well. Will get back to you if and when I have any issues :)

Comment: Another thing to consider; if you can figure out how to distribute multiplication unevenly across your x, then you could use [tf.segment_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/segment_sum). (e.g. softmax; you can easily calculate the divisors, but I couldn't find a graceful way of dividing a subset of the elements of an arbitrary size with broadcasting-like behaviour)